# Rspec testing to_param override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I failed to google anything about this, so I bring it here.
I've overrode to_param on my model to concatenate it with the id for a prettier and safer URL.  I'm at a loss where this should have been in my test.  It seems like putting it to a routing test misses the point.  I would think that this would go in the model's spec, though:

```
#my model
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    [id,an_attr.parameterize].join("-")
  end
end
#my model spec
describe MyModel do
  mymodel = MyModel.create!(:an_attr => "test attr")
  mymodel.to_param should == [mymodel.id,"test_attr"].join("-")
end
```

What I get is:

```
 Failure/Error: mymodel.to_param should == [mymodel.id,"test_attr"].join("-")
   expected: "1-test_atttr"
        got: #<MyModel id: nil, an_attr: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> (using ==)
```

A model instance...I've got to be missing something obvious here --- maybe its just late for me---
insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a period after `to_param`.

`mymodel.to_param.should == [mymodel.id,"test_attr"].join("-")`

Comment: doh!... yeah. that certainly was it... so would this be the appropriate place/way to test a URL slug? Doesn't seem like you'd want to do it in the router as you'd have to stub a model, right?